# Cannot find 'Swiftv' in scope

Tags: swift, xcode

I have this error in my Xcode and also in vs.

Has anyone experienced this problem? I couldn't find anyone anywhere on the Internet who had this error.

> Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 14 Pro Max in debug mode...
> Xcode build done.                                           134,1s
> Failed to build iOS app
> Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Cannot find 'Swiftv' in scope
> /Users/andersonolsen/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/connectivity_plus-5.0.2/ios/Classes/SwiftConnectivityPlusPlugin.swift:32:19

> Could not build the application for the simulator.
> Error launching application on iPhone 14 Pro Max.

---

```
import Flutter

public class SwiftConnectivityPlusPlugin: NSObject, FlutterPlugin, FlutterStreamHandler {
  private let connectivityProvider: ConnectivityProvider
  private var eventSink: FlutterEventSink?

  init(connectivityProvider: ConnectivityProvider) {
    self.connectivityProvider = connectivityProvider
    super.init()
    self.connectivityProvider.connectivityUpdateHandler = connectivityUpdateHandler
  }

  public static func register(with registrar: FlutterPluginRegistrar) {
    let channel = FlutterMethodChannel(
      name: "dev.fluttercommunity.plus/connectivity",
      binaryMessenger: registrar.messenger())

    let streamChannel = FlutterEventChannel(
      name: "dev.fluttercommunity.plus/connectivity_status",
      binaryMessenger: registrar.messenger())

    let connectivityProvider: ConnectivityProvider
    if #available(iOS 12, *) {
      connectivityProvider = PathMonitorConnectivityProvider()
    } else {
      connectivityProvider = ReachabilityConnectivityProvider()
    }

    let instance = Swiftv(connectivityProvider: connectivityProvider)
    streamChannel.setStreamHandler(instance)

    registrar.addMethodCallDelegate(instance, channel: channel)
  }
```

[image: Error Xcode]

Comment: How would your showing a screenshot indicating that you have an error help other people track down the cause?

Comment: You are trying to instantiate a `Swiftv` instance and this class cannot be found. So either you are missing an `import` for the framework where the class is defined, or it's a typo and shouldn't be `Swiftv` at all. Since you are trying to set the instance as the stream handler on a `FlutterEventChannel`, it is probably supposed to be implementing the protocol `FlutterStreamHandler`. I would suggest going to the API docs for more clues.